# What to put into 'init.el' vs 'config.el' in Org-mode?

Tags: init-file, org-babel, config

I'm using Org-mode to configure Emacs in a file 'config.el', which is really unstructured meanwhile. On the other hand, lots of configurations (for exemple the configs made with the menu) are in Emacs' own 'init.el'.

I would like now to put all the stuff not needed in the 'init.el' to the 'config.el' in order to get it organized with Org-mode.

So what is the difference between these files, and what is the minimal content of 'init.el'?

Comment: But I guess BABEL will need at least two files, one where BABEL is initiated and another one to load and write?

Comment: No, you don't need multiple files: you can do it all in your `${HOME}/.emacs.d/init.el` file. Most people start like that and after a while find that they want to "tidy up" things: there are many ways to "tidy up" and emacs does not force you to use one over any other (or any at all for that matter). You will have to use your judgment and your experience to decide what's good for your purposes. Studying the init files of other people can help, but you should just *start* and not worry too much about  a (mythical) "perfection".

Comment: Thank's a lot for Your encouragement!

Answer (score 1):

> what is the difference between these files?

`init.el` is a standard Emacs init filename, and `config.el` is something you've invented.

> what is the minimal content of 'init.el'?

Nothing.  Empty.  Emacs doesn't require that the file exist at all.